# Grant permission for new created files inside folder automatically

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, acl

I have a folder which permission is set to 777 but when I add any files or folder unziping in that folder. Extracted files or folder permission never change. Destination folder permission is 777 and I want what I will add in that folder will automatically get permission of 777.

When I add any files or folder by extracting .zip in that folder, extracted folder/files permission won't change automatically. I always have to chmod for newly add file/folder!

Comment: What is the [umask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html) set to un the account which is extracting the files?

Comment: @Hennes, thanks to mention about umask, I didn't know much about that. After your comments, I have searched google and learnt more about it. By that, I have solved my problem partially though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you want is called **ACL** - [Access Control Lists](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists).

> Access Control List (ACL) provides an additional, more flexible
> permission mechanism for file systems. It is designed to assist with
> UNIX file permissions. ACL allows you to give permissions for any user
> or group to any disc resource.

`acl` package should be already installed, to check it run: `dpkg -s acl`.

To use ACL's you should enable it for your filesystem. But it can be **already enabled**. To check it use `tune2fs -l`. Substitute `/dev/sda6` for your system:

```
$ tune2fs -l /dev/sda6 | grep "Default mount options:"
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
```

If you see **acl** word - it is already enabled for device `/dev/sda6`.

If you don't see **acl** word - run `tune2fs -o acl /dev/sda6` to enable it.

---

> To modify ACL use **setfacl** command. To add permissions use **setfacl -m**.

### To set permission for user:

```
$ setfacl -m "u:username:rwx" /path/to/folder
```

This will set `rwx` ACL, for user `username` to /path/to/folder. This means that all files created in this folder will have `rwx` permission for `username`.

---

### To set permission for group:

```
$ setfacl -m "g:groupname:rwx" /path/to/folder
```

This will set `rwx` ACL, for group `groupname` to /path/to/folder. This means that all files created in this folder will have `rwx` permission for group `groupname`.

---

### To set permission for other:

```
$ setfacl -m "o:rwx" /path/to/folder
```

This will set `rwx` ACL, for other to /path/to/folder. This means that all files created in this folder will have `rwx` permission for other.

---

### To check permission:

```
$ getfacl /path/to/folder
```

---

### To combine acl

```
$ setfacl -m u:username:rwx,g:groupname:rwx,o:rwx /path/to/folder
```

---

## Default ACL

```
 The new object inherits the default ACL of the containing directory as its
 access ACL.

 If no default ACL is associated with a directory, the mode parameter to the func‐
 tions creating file objects and the file creation mask (see umask(2)) are used to
 determine the ACL of the new object:

 The new object is assigned an access ACL containing entries of tag types
 ACL_USER_OBJ, ACL_GROUP_OBJ, and ACL_OTHER. The permissions of these entries
 are set to the permissions specified by the file creation mask.
```

So if you set default ACL, it would be **preferred** ACL. That means if set ACL for `user` or `group`, new created file would inherit **default** acl **anyway**. Be carefully with default ACL.

To set default acl use `-d` key,

```
$ setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx /path/to/folder
```

or use `default` word

```
$ setfacl -m default:u::rwx,default:g::rwx,default:o::rwx /path/to/folder
```

Be carefully with setting default ACL. For example if set like this:

```
$ setfacl -d -m o:--x /path/to/folder
```

and now fetch this ACL

```
$ getfacl /path/to/folder
# file: path/to/folder
# owner: c0rp
# group: c0rp
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::--x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::--x
```

**default ACL for group and user will be `rwx` automatically!**

### Remove ACL

```
$ setfacl -b /path/to/folder
```

This will remove all ACL's from folder

---

### Finally

If you are only user in system, I recommend use default ACL.

```
$ setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx /path/to/folder
```

This will do what you want for /path/to/folder

### Sources

[archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists

[help.ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

Comment: Well this is awesome and complete answer! Thank you @c0rp