# how to give full permissions to a specific user for a folder?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

I am completely new to Ubuntu.

There are 4 user groups in my Ubuntu 13.04 (32bit).

In user group `ceo`, there is only one user `chief`.

There is a folder in Home (default Personal folder) which is named `ITSM Lab1`.

There are subfolders with files inside `ITSM Lab1`.

I want to give user `chief` or group `ceo` **Full permissions** for the folder `ITSM Lab1` and everything inside it (and Full permissions will also be given to future subfolders and files).

What is the command to do these?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i edited the question body

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. You can set the group of the folder `ITSM Lab1` to be `ceo` and give full access to the group for this folder and its subfolders.

Recursively change **group** for the folder and its subfolders:

```
chgrp -R ceo ITSM Lab1
```

Recursively change permission for a group:

```
chmod g+rwx ceo ITSM Lab1
```

2. You can set the owner of the folder `ITSM Lab1` to be `chief` and give full access to that user for this folder and its subfolders.

Recursively change **owner** for the folder and its subfolders:

```
chown -R chief ITSM Lab1
```

Recursively change permission for a group:

```
chmod u+rwx chief ITSM Lab1
```

The below links to the `man page` will provide more info about the command used above:

- [chmod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chmod.1.html)
- [chown](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chown.1.html)
- [chgrp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chgrp.1.html)

Comment: what does this do:  chgrp -R ceo ITSM Lab1 ?

Comment: @kaly - it will set the group of the folder `ITSM LAB1` and its sub-folders to  the group `ceo`.

Comment: Can I give full permission to more than one groups for a certain folder (and everything inside) ?

Comment: @kali - see full answer in the [duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465381/grant-permission-for-new-created-files-inside-folder-automatically) kindly found for you by muru

Comment: with this command 'chgrp -R ceo ITSM_Lab1' , i cannot set two groups for a folder. Only one group can be set. That's a problem :(

Comment: @kali - see  full answer in the duplicate question kindly found for you by muru