# Automatic 777 permissions on new files and folders inside htdocs apache2 folder

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, apache2, php

I want to set 777 permissions to all new files and folders inside apache2 /var/www/html/apps/

When I extract zip file or create new file, I give 777 permissions via terminal, but this process needs to be done every time. Therefore, I am looking for a solution to make it permanent.

I tried below commands, as per old post URL but not working.

URL => [Grant permission for new created files inside folder automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465381/grant-permission-for-new-created-files-inside-folder-automatically)

```
getfacl /var/www/html/apps/

setfacl -m "u:zohaib:rwx" /var/www/html/apps/

setfacl -m "o:rwx" /var/www/html/apps/

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/apps/
```

Any idea?

Best Regards,
Zohaib

Comment: "Any idea?" Yeah 1... -NOT- a good idea.

Comment: @Rinzwind I was writing the same thing, 775 would be better, notably blocking virus execution

Comment: I want to install magento and other php open source softwares, they require 777 for development on local machine for some folders Since I am not running live website therefore I think it will be fine. Any idea about 755 permanent permission.

Comment: @shahab No they do not.  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/before/before-workspace-file-sys-owner.html where does it say it requires 777 for development?

Comment: [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html) i used this along time ago.

Comment: ***777 is bad, do not use it for default options or permissions!***

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to set up a webserver is to set the user and the group of files to the user and group you set up the webserver with. You will find a ...

```
User {user}
Group {group}
```

inside the apache configuration file as an example. The default, for apache, is likely `www-data`. Other webservers will have a similar method. You can match your files with this user and group with:

```
sudo chown -R {user}:{group} /var/www/
```

where {user} and {group} need to match those from the configuration. [Magento](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/before/before-workspace-file-sys-owner.html) uses the apache user and group but you need to set it up manually.

`chmod` should not be needed to set up apache and if you need to use it it is more likely an indication something else is wrong.

A method to set up your directories and files inside /var/www/html/ that has the highest possible needed permissions for a correctly working webserver are:

```
find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

- `-d` means directory, `-f` means file.
- 1st digit: "user" should be able to do whatever is need.
- 2nd digit: "group" can be set to 0 stricly speaking.
- 3rd digit: "others" have nothing to do inside your website.

Please take security serious when using a webserver.

Comment: thanks for details friends. sorry Magento do not need 777 but I was giving on my local apache2 server on ubuntu.